# Grunt mustache_render won't render HTML file correctly

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mustache

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-mustache-render to render a HTML file using a layout file and json file.

Here is the Grunt task:

```
mustache_render: {
      json_data: {
        files: [
          {
            data: 'output.json',
            template: 'test.mustache',
            dest: 'tmp/hello_json.html'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Output JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "30"
  },
  {
   "name": "Alex Len",
    "age": "27"
  },
  {
   "name": "Debbie John",
    "age": "36"
  }

]
```

test.mustache looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Mustache Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Titles</h2>
  <ul id="talktitles">
    <script id="speakers-template" type="text/template">
    {{#options}}
      <li>{{{name}}}, {{{age}}}</li>
    {{/options}}
  </script>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run grunt it created the tmp/hello_json.html file but the values are not populated. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Mustache Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Titles</h2>
  <ul id="talktitles">
    <script id="speakers-template" type="text/template">
  </script>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `output.json` doesn't conform with template. Template waits `options` value in json file, but there is not such key.

Correct output json should be like this one:

```
{
  options: [{
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": "30"
    }, {
      "name": "Alex Len",
      "age": "27"
    }, {
     "name": "Debbie John",
     "age": "36"
    }]
}
```

### Addition

Also you have an ability to refer root of the json file with `.`
So you can change your template part to this

```
    {{#.}}
      <li>{{{name}}}, {{{age}}}</li>
    {{/.}}
```

Comment: What if there is no 'options' key in the JSON? How will I iterate through the json data then? UPDATE: Thanks for the Addition.

Comment: Worked fine. Thanks :)